# Convergent/divergent series: comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Determine if the series
$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{( \ln \ln n)^{\ln \ln n}} $$
converges.

The terms of the sequence do not go to zero and the ratio test gives no useful information, so I am trying to find a series to compare it with. I am pretty sure that the series diverges, so I'm trying to compare it with $1/n$ but am getting stuck.

Comment: Not relevant  to your actual question, but start the series at $n=3$ or something : $\ln \ln 2 < 0$, and raising it to a non-integral power is problematic

Comment: "The terms of the sequence do not go to zero": they do, otherwise the answer would be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical case for Cauchy condensation test.

Let replace $a_n=\dfrac 1{\ln\ln(n)^{\ln\ln(n)}}$ by $b_n=2^na_{2^n}$ to get the condensed series

$b_n=\dfrac {2^n}{\ln(n\ln(2))^{\ln(n\ln(2))}}$

And let's do it again

$c_n=\dfrac{2^n2^{2^n}}{(\ln\ln(2)+n\ln(2))^{(\ln\ln(2)+n\ln(2))}}$

The denominator in $(a+bn)^{a+bn}$ is roughly in $(bn)^{bn}$ which is negligible compared to $2^{2^n}$ on the numerator, so $c_n\not\to 0$.

So the series $\sum c_n$ is divergent as well as $\sum b_n$ and eventually $\sum a_n$.

*Note: if we could do it with $e$ instead of $2$, the condensation test would lead immediately to a more visual result, indeed we would get:
$c_n=\dfrac{e^ne^{e^n}}{n^n}=\exp(n+e^n-n\ln(n))\sim \exp(e^n)\to\infty$. Unfortunately the test requires integer indices, and we have to deal with these annoying $\ln(2)$ terms. But doing so gives a good indication whether the series converges or not.*

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the general term of the series in a less confusing form. For any (sufficient big, so that the quantity $\ln\ln n$ is defined) integer $n$,
$$
(\ln\ln n)^{\ln\ln n}
= e^{\ln\ln n\cdot \ln\ln\ln n}\,.
$$
Now, we have
$$
n = e^{\ln n}
$$
and since
$$
\ln n > (\ln \ln n)^2 > \ln\ln n\cdot \ln\ln\ln n
$$
for $n$ big enough (and $\exp$ is increasing), it follows that
$$
n > (\ln\ln n)^{\ln\ln n}
$$
for $n$ big enough, and therefore (again for $n$ big enough)
$$
\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{(\ln\ln n)^{\ln\ln n}}\,.
$$
You can now conclude by comparison to $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: This can also be solved by integral test which makes it easy to convert logarithms to exponentials easily.